# Using all dimensions with postgis functions

Tags: postgis-1.5

I have points as geometry format in table that I use for some analysis. All points are saved in four dimensions eg. x, y, z and m - lon, lat, alt and time. The issue is that for the analysis are used functions like ST_GeomFromEWKT and ST_MakeLine, which included only two dimensions form the four present.

My specific questions is can I have the four dimensions using these functions?

I tried simple example

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(1, 1, 0, 1339590840), ST_MakePoint(2, 2, 0, 1339590840)));
```

Which returns "LINESTRING(1 1,2 2)", without z and time dimensions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostGIS has only limited functions for dealing with 3D and 4D geometries. As you already found out, ST_MakePoint is [one of the few](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.0/reference.html#Geometry_Outputs) (search for 4d). Check if you have better luck with running them through [ST_Force_4D](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_Force_4D.html) first.

Comment: Thanks! Tried ST_Force_4D and ST_Force3DM and either are not working as I want. SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Force_4D(point)) from gps_data LIMIT 1 returns "POINT(-122.084091186523 37.422004699707)" with no z and m dimensions, but the point has it (can get with st_z() and st_m()). Will look for other solution...